# How do I get New York City time?

Tags: python

I travel frequently but live in NYC and am trying to display NYC time no matter where I am. How do I do that in Python? I have the following, which doesn't work, giving me the error:

```
 `'module' object is not callable`
```

Also, I'm not sure if my method below will correctly update with daylight savings time or not:

```
import pytz
utc = pytz.utc
utc_dt = datetime(2002, 10, 27, 6, 0, 0, tzinfo=utc)
eastern = pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')
loc_dt = utc_dt.astimezone(eastern)
fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z%z'
loc_dt.strftime(fmt)
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Instead of `datetime`, write `datetime.datetime`:

```
import datetime
import pytz

utc = pytz.utc
utc_dt = datetime.datetime(2002, 10, 27, 6, 0, 0, tzinfo=utc)
eastern = pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')
loc_dt = utc_dt.astimezone(eastern)
fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z%z'
loc_dt.strftime(fmt)
```

That's because the module [datetime](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html) contains a class [`datetime.datetime`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime).

Answer (score 11):

You can get a `datetime` object of the current time in a specific timezone using the `now()` method in the following fashion:

```
import datetime, pytz
nyc_datetime = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone('US/Eastern'))
```

Answer (score 8):

It's cleaner to write your import like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz
now = datetime.now(tz=pytz.timezone('US/Eastern'))
```

This allows re-use of datetime further down your code, without having to datetime.datetime every single time. Also avoids importing the entire datetime module unnecessarily.

Also note that according to IANA, 'US/Eastern' has been deprecated. Perhaps consider 'America/New_York'

Answer (score 3):

i will do this instead:

```
import datetime
import pytz
now = datetime.datetime.now(tz=pytz.timezone('US/Eastern'))
print("now time is: ", now)
current_hour = now.hour
current_minute = now.minute
current_second = now.second
current_weekday = now.weekday()
```

Answer (score 2):

New in Python 3.9, you may choose **zoneinfo** instead of third party library

```
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo
from datetime import datetime
dt = datetime(2022, 11, 16, 1, tzinfo=ZoneInfo("US/Eastern"))
fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z%z'
dt.strftime(fmt)
```